# Gradle Android: How to Display test results without using --info

Tags: android, gradle

I am running android tests using the Gradle Android plugin and want to see individual test results.

From answers to this Question [Gradle: How to Display Test Results in the Console in Real Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963708/gradle-how-to-display-test-results-in-the-console-in-real-time) it seems I can either use `--info` (which prints a LOT of other verbose junk I don't care about) or use this closure which only works for the Java plugin (not the Android plugin)

```
test {
    afterTest { desc, result -> 
        println "Executing test ${desc.name} [${desc.className}] with result: ${result.resultType}"
    }
}
```

Is there some other option / closure I can use when I am running the `connectedCheck` task just to print the individual test results without all the other "verbosity".

Comment: This is possibly with the `Robolectric Gradle Plugin` if you using `Robolectric` but this will only show the `test` and the result:`success`/`fail`. I think you best bet is you display the "full exception" for when a test fails in the console. All HTML test results are generated in your `build/reports/tests`.

Comment: I do not use Roboelectric - just the plain vanilla androidTests

Comment: Yeah, I believe you have it figured out. `--info` is your best bet. Adding `Robolectric` is really simply and you can just add it in order to use their plugin https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin.

Comment: For errors, you want this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24388879/950427

Comment: Our tests take a long time to run so i want to see the successes as well as the failures just to have confidence that nothing terrible has blown up

Comment: Does your build not fail on the first test case failure? Check out the link I posted, it will print out all failure exceptions as well as `expected`/`was`.

Comment: I came across something that may help answer this.

Comment: What is the status of this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Use `Gradle` info

This will print all information from `Gradle`:

```
gradle --info
```

### or Use Android `Gradle` plugin:

```
android.testOptions.unitTests.all {
    // Configure whether failing tests should fail the build
    ignoreFailures false

    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
    }
}
```

### or Use `Gradle` directly:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        testLogging {
            exceptionFormat "full"
            showCauses true
            showExceptions true
            showStackTraces true
            showStandardStreams true
            events = ["passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"]
        }
    }
}
```

See: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/android-gradle-java-app-template/blob/master/gradle/compile.gradle#L20

**Output:**

```
io.github.hidroh.materialistic.data.SessionManagerTest > testView PASSED

io.github.hidroh.materialistic.data.SessionManagerTest > testIsViewFalse PASSED

io.github.hidroh.materialistic.data.SessionManagerTest > testIsViewNull PASSED

io.github.hidroh.materialistic.data.SessionManagerTest > testIsViewTrue PASSED

io.github.hidroh.materialistic.data.SessionManagerTest > testViewNoId PASSED
```

**Source:** https://github.com/hidroh/materialistic/blob/master/robolectric.gradle

**Gradle Docs:** https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/logging/TestLogEvent.html

Comment: Do you know how this can be applied to all gradle (library) modules in a project? Putting it in the top-level build.gradle fails as `android` isn't recognised, and putting it in the app module only prints output for tests in that module.

Comment: @user1405990 Use `allprojects` with `tasks.withType(Test)`

Answer (score 4):

For me all the options mentioned in the other answer still printed a lot of verbose information. So despite the requirement that info should not be used, I successfully use the following. For example, if your tests are in the package `com.example.android`, you can use:

```
gradle --info connectedDebugAndroidTest | grep "com\.example\.android\..* >"
```

Will print e. g.:

```
 com.example.android.login.LoginActivityTest > enterCredentialsTest[Testing_emulator(AVD) - 9] SUCCESS
```

And the word "SUCCESS" will be green, which is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

For Android Studio (tested on com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0 and gradle version gradle-2.10) I added the following section to print exceptions in full format as **well as logging every executed test**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android { ... }

dependencies { ...}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat "full"
    }
    afterTest { desc, result ->
        println "Executing test ${desc.name} [${desc.className}] with result: ${result.resultType}"
    }
}
```