# Gradle: How to display androidTest results in the console?

Tags: android, gradle, integration-testing, android-testing

As explained in other threads Gradle can be configured to log test results into the console:

- [Gradle Android: How to Display test results without using --info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308435/gradle-android-how-to-display-test-results-without-using-info)
- [Gradle: How to Display Test Results in the Console in Real Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963708/gradle-how-to-display-test-results-in-the-console-in-real-time)
- [Output unit testing results on console using spock junit testing and gradle build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360099/output-unit-testing-results-on-console-using-spock-junit-testing-and-gradle-buil)

Basically, this can be setup through the following task:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
       // Custom configuration
    }
}
```

This works fine for unit tests and looks somewhat like this:

```
...
:app:assembleDebugUnitTest
:app:testDebugUnitTest
:app:processDebugResources

com.example.StringsTest > formatValue PASSED
com.example.StringsTest > formatValueWithDecimals FAILED

1 test completed, 1 failed
```

Besides, unit tests I also run **integration test** using the following command:

```
$ ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

When I look at the output in the console I am **missing the individual test** results as being written for unit tests. How can I configure test logging for instrumentation tests?

Comment: Any luck with this JJD?

Comment: Not yet. To be honest I had to delay these tests for a while. I will pick it up as soon as things are "back to normal". Did you try hidro's approach?

Comment: Nah, I just wanted a Gradle based approach. I was hoping something like `tasks.withTest`.

Answer (score 13):

Connected tests log output and events to `logcat`, as it runs on a device/emulator. Test events are logged under `TestRunner` tag.

I use the following script to start `adb logcat` in the background, which logs `TestRunner` events as tests are being executed, and kill the `logcat` process afterwards.

```
adb logcat *:S TestRunner:V -T 1 & LOGCAT_PID=$! ; \
./gradlew :app:cAT ; \
if [ -n "$LOGCAT_PID" ] ; then kill $LOGCAT_PID; fi
```

which produces something like this:

```
[1] 90439
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
...
:app:packageDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
> Building 96% > :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest06-13 09:25:04.259  5460  5474 I TestRunner: run started: 23 tests
06-13 09:25:04.267  5460  5474 I TestRunner: started: testHomeClick(io.github.hidroh.tldroid.CommandActivityTest)
06-13 09:25:06.899  5460  5474 I TestRunner: finished: testHomeClick(io.github.hidroh.tldroid.CommandActivityTest)
06-13 09:25:06.903  5460  5474 I TestRunner: started: testRenderNoContent(io.github.hidroh.tldroid.CommandActivityTest)
06-13 09:25:08.128  5460  5474 I TestRunner: finished: testRenderNoContent(io.github.hidroh.tldroid.CommandActivityTest)
06-13 09:25:08.130  5460  5474 I TestRunner: started: testStateRestoration(io.github.hidroh.tldroid.CommandActivityTest)
06-13 09:25:09.547  5460  5474 I TestRunner: finished: testStateRestoration(io.github.hidroh.tldroid.CommandActivityTest)
...
06-13 09:25:35.283  5460  5474 I TestRunner: run finished: 23 tests, 0 failed, 0 ignored
:app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
:app:createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport
:app:connectedAndroidTest

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 7.485 secs
[1]+  Terminated: 15          adb logcat *:S TestRunner:V
```

You can of course tweak `logcat` command to use a logger of your choice, e.g. a color logger, or change `logcat filterspec` to show more events.

Comment: Works perfectly! Even though it's not "gradle based approach"

Comment: FYI: Added `-T 1` to avoid the long listing before running tests.

Answer (score 6):

The easy version is just to use:

> ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest --info

it take a littlebit to log it in the terminal/console window, but it's showing everything nice, colored and formatted

like …

```
…ShowsIntroduction[SM-G950F - 7.0] SUCCESS 
…BackButtonReturnsToOnboardingScreen[SM-G950F - 7.0] SKIPPED
```

good luck && have fun